# Pandas Python probelm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

```
import pandas as pd
nba = pd.read_csv("nba.csv")
names = pd.Series(nba['Name'])
data = nba['Salary']
nba_series = (data, index=[names])
print(nba_series)
```

Hello I am trying to convert the columns 'Name' and 'Salary' into a series from a dataframe. I need to set the names as the index and the salaries as the values but i cannot figure it out. this is my best attempt so far anyone guidance is appreciated

Comment: Right now, `nba_series` is just a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over-thinking this. Simply construct it with `pd.Series()`. Note the data needs to be with `.values`, otherwis eyou'll get `Nan`s

```
import pandas as pd
nba = pd.read_csv("nba.csv")
nba_series = pd.Series(data=nba['Salary'].values, index=nba['Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `set_index`?

```
nba.set_index('name',  inlace = True )
nba_series = nba['Salary']
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
import pandas as pd
nba = pd.read_csv("nba.csv")
names = nba['Name']
#It's automatically a series
data = nba['Salary']
#Set names as index of series 
data.index = nba_series
```

Answer (score 0):

data.index = names might be correct but depends on the data